# Prevent overlapping Div

Tags: html, css

I'm at a loss on trying to get my content body to end at the bottom of the screen before my footer. What am I missing?

```
<body class="v4master">
    <form id="aspnetForm">
        <div id="SharingBoundaryHeader">Banner</div>
        <div id="s4-ribbonrow">Ribbon</div>
        <div id="s4-titlerow">Title Row</div>
        <div id="s4-workspace">WorkSpace
            </p></br>Aenean ex diam, tincidunt eu risus sit amet, condimentum cursus nunc. Nulla viverra ligula quis leo porttitor mattis. Proin at nibh sed nibh consectetur iaculis. Donec accumsan finibus ipsum. Cras aliquet velit condimentum urna fringilla molestie. Vivamus vitae ultrices tellus. Curabitur ac mi sit amet nisl posuere sollicitudin. Vestibulum sodales purus ac accumsan vulputate. Donec semper orci ac lorem volutpat euismod. Donec faucibus massa finibus erat commodo pharetra. Integer facilisis pretium pharetra. Curabitur auctor viverra sodales.
        </div>
        <div id="ctl00_IdLMFooter_footer">Footer</div>
    </form>
</body>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JFlattery/23n76huL/)

Edit:
I want it to look like [this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f61SH.png) but with the inner scroll-bar active when the content overflows instead of the outer one.

Comment: Just remove the styling (positioning) for `#ctl00_IdLMFooter_footer` and it as at the bottom of the content. Or maybe I don't understand what you want. Can you draw a picture?

Comment: Am I understanding you want the user to have to scroll for the footer?

Comment: I want the footer to always be at the bottom of the window, regardless of how much content is in `workspace`

Comment: Use `position:fixed` for the footer.

Comment: @MrLister: Than the content (including the scroll-bar) are behind and cutoff by the footer. http://jsfiddle.net/JFlattery/23n76huL/1/

Answer (score 0):

The footer needs `position: relative`

http://jsfiddle.net/23n76huL/4/

*I initally stated that you needed `position: absolute` on the form, but this is not necessary.*

```
#ctl00_IdLMFooter_footer {
    position:relative;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your CSS see if you get what you are looking for.

```
#s4-workspace {
position: absolute;
bottom:20px;
}

#ctl00_IdLMFooter_footer {
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be overkill but here is a dynamic version using javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/23n76huL/7/

```
var height1 = document.getElementById('SharingBoundaryHeader').offsetHeight,
    height2 = document.getElementById('s4-ribbonrow').offsetHeight,
    height3 = document.getElementById('s4-titlerow').offsetHeight,
    //height4 = document.getElementById('s4-workspace').offsetHeight,
    height5 = document.getElementById('ctl00_IdLMFooter_footer').offsetHeight,
    bodyheight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight,
    a = 0;

a = bodyheight - (height1 + height2 + height3 + height5 + 2);

document.getElementById('s4-workspace').style.height = a + "px";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/23n76huL/9/

CSS

```
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#ctl00_IdLMFooter_footer {
   background: white;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
#s4-workspace {
    position:relative;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
body {
    height:auto;
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.content {
    height: 100vh;
    border: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<body class="v4master">
    <form id="aspnetForm">
        <div id="SharingBoundaryHeader">Banner</div>
        <div id="s4-ribbonrow">Ribbon</div>
        <div id="s4-titlerow">Title Row</div>
        <div id="s4-workspace">
            <div class="content">
                WorkSpace
            </p></br>Aenean ex diam, tincidunt eu risus sit amet, condimentum cursus nunc. Nulla viverra ligula quis leo porttitor mattis. Proin at nibh sed nibh consectetur iaculis. Donec accumsan finibus ipsum. Cras aliquet velit condimentum urna fringilla molestie. Vivamus vitae ultrices tellus. Curabitur ac mi sit amet nisl posuere sollicitudin. Vestibulum sodales purus ac accumsan vulputate. Donec semper orci ac lorem volutpat euismod. Donec faucibus massa finibus erat commodo pharetra. Integer facilisis pretium pharetra. Curabitur auctor viverra sodales.

            Integer cursus ornare lobortis. Ut felis tellus, tincidunt vitae finibus lobortis, mollis aliquet tortor. In molestie lacus justo, eget viverra ante viverra id. Fusce vehicula nibh quis molestie lacinia. Aenean ultricies lorem eros, vehicula commodo lectus feugiat tempus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean sit amet felis tincidunt, efficitur sem sed, bibendum erat. Fusce a tellus in nisl tempor hendrerit at non ligula. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec lorem ligula, pharetra ut mi vel, pharetra auctor felis. Fusce erat orci, sodales at dapibus vitae, viverra non lorem. Curabitur tincidunt mi imperdiet est mattis ultricies.

            Integer magna lorem, aliquam a lobortis et, pulvinar et eros. Nullam consectetur semper dui, condimentum venenatis mi ultricies non. Suspendisse non maximus felis. Praesent cursus est a sollicitudin commodo. Sed enim risus, varius id sagittis sed, tempor et orci. Nulla vestibulum nulla id arcu tincidunt sagittis. Nunc eu est quis massa iaculis laoreet et ut odio. Praesent feugiat felis a neque pulvinar ultrices. Donec eget leo dui. Nulla in eros sit amet quam iaculis euismod eget ut augue. Ut vitae hendrerit velit. Quisque massa sem, vulputate id nunc ut, lacinia cursus turpis. Proin lobortis, enim sed varius sollicitudin, urna dolor mollis mauris, et sodales tortor metus non sapien. Quisque eget mauris vitae mi dapibus tincidunt. Praesent eget posuere odio, ac dictum diam.

            Sed rutrum libero vel dui volutpat egestas. Nullam ultricies dignissim nunc non tristique. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur vel enim eget tortor dictum rutrum. Aliquam a lacus id diam luctus faucibus eu eget neque. Nullam ut lacus lacinia, pellentesque ipsum sit amet, consectetur sem. Proin tristique eleifend nisi vitae sollicitudin. Aliquam accumsan orci eget libero sollicitudin, vitae tempus diam blandit. Vestibulum quam dui, viverra vel commodo id, dapibus at erat.

            Etiam interdum varius pellentesque. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla venenatis posuere elementum. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque varius accumsan enim. Donec molestie urna at arcu posuere egestas. Praesent mattis nisi ut erat euismod, a venenatis velit viverra. Vestibulum ultricies tempus eleifend. Nulla vitae dui suscipit, hendrerit tortor quis, viverra urna. Pellentesque et varius turpis. Morbi in risus vel elit euismod pharetra. Cras ut mi in ligula venenatis vulputate non in nibh. Sed quis sapien eget sapien blandit viverra. Donec sed magna eget lacus sodales consectetur. 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="ctl00_IdLMFooter_footer">Footer</div>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: This is close to what I want, but how can I get the scroll-bar inside of '#s4-workspac' ?

Comment: Use `overflow-y:scroll;` on div you want to scroll and also you must set height on `content` of that div